keyboard shortcut does not work for code chunk in VS code
I am learning how to run Rmd filed using VS code.
I have set up and all code chunks are working and i just cant figure out the keyborad shortcuts:

I use this shortcut to run the selected word (eg dataset name). But it does not work for me, nothing is run when I press ctrl+sht+eneter. but ctrl+eneter works- the entire code chunk is run. So the issue is not in code chunk itself, but a shortcut
What I am really looking for is to have a shortcut that will run a line or selection where my cursor is.
output from Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting
2024-04-22 12:23:49.952 [info] Started local extension host with pid 18060.
2024-04-22 12:23:50.508 [warning] [REditorSupport.r]: Cannot register 'r.rpath.windows'. This property is already registered.
2024-04-22 12:23:50.509 [warning] [REditorSupport.r]: Cannot register 'r.rpath.mac'. This property is already registered.
2024-04-22 12:23:50.509 [warning] [REditorSupport.r]: Cannot register 'r.rpath.linux'. This property is already registered.
2024-04-22 12:23:54.704 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 52ms
2024-04-22 12:29:16.830 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-04-22 12:29:16.831 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2024-04-22 12:29:16.831 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
2024-04-22 12:29:16.832 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
2024-04-22 12:29:16.832 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2024-04-22 12:29:17.222 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-04-22 12:29:17.223 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2024-04-22 12:29:17.223 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 16, key: Shift
2024-04-22 12:29:17.223 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 4 ('Shift')
2024-04-22 12:29:17.223 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2024-04-22 12:29:17.452 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-04-22 12:29:17.452 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+shift+Enter
2024-04-22 12:29:17.452 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
2024-04-22 12:29:17.453 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: Enter, keyCode: 13, key: Enter
2024-04-22 12:29:17.453 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: Enter, keyCode: 3 ('Enter')
2024-04-22 12:29:17.453 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+shift+Enter
2024-04-22 12:29:17.453 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
2024-04-22 12:29:17.969 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
2024-04-22 12:29:56.956 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-04-22 12:29:56.956 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched

and then from Developer: Inspect Key Mappings
Default Resolved Keybindings (unique only):
 ...
ctrl+shift+Enter =>                    ctrl+shift+Enter
...
User Resolved Keybindings (unique only):
ctrl+enter =>                          ctrl+Enter
ctrl+shift+enter =>                    ctrl+shift+Enter

the JSON of the keybinding is the following
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+enter",
  "command": "r.runSelection",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'r'"
}

Here what I see when I inspect context keys and use the keybiniding in my RMD file:


What do you see when you troubleshoot your keybindings? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running Developer: Inspect Key Mappings in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.

the key part of the message is "no when clauses matched the context". please right click the keybinding in the keybinding UI, copy it as JSON, and paste the JSON of the keybinding into your question post. You can also inspect context keys- find out what the values of the related context keys are when you invoke the keybinding.

@user- thanks a ton! it worked,  what if i want to have this key for both 'r' and 'rmd'?

Assuming you're using REditorSupport.r, then you probably want to use editorLangId == 'rmd' instead. Related source code is in its extension manifest. If you want the keybinding for both R and Rmd files, then use (editorLangId == 'r' || editorLangId == 'rmd').
